# Changing WSDL url: from ?wsdl to .wsdl

Tags: c#, jboss, wsdl

I have a java web service deployed on JBoss Server 4.2.3 GA
The generated wsdl uses "?"

There are clients in .NET who are accessing the WSDL on their side.
Earlier the clients used to get like ".wsdl" to access the web service. 
Now they want the same .wsdl instead of ?wsdl.

Kindly suggest how to redirect or change some configuration to provide the .wsdl url to the client.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Clients get whatever URL they are configured to get. There's nothing wrong with `?wsdl`.

Comment: Have you considered using URL rewriting to fix the issue?